# angular fetch list of files from url

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to get list of files in a directory on a server. I have an url and from browser i can see all the files. I need to get them and see the name of those files

I've tried something like this, that i looked up online but i don't understand it

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var test = this.getListFileFromServer()
    debugger
  }

  getListFileFromServer() {
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: "blob" })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        // a.href = URL.createObjectURL(res.blob());
        debugger

        // a.click();
      })
    // .catch((err) => { console.error('error retrieving list of bins') })
    // return this.http.get(url,
    //   { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

can you help?

Comment: what's the content of the `res` variable?

Comment: @MartinoBordin this is what i see in dev tools: size: 479
type: "text/html"
[[Prototype]]: Blob

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @Batajus i don't understand how too get a list of the files in the remote directory

Comment: Can ou remove the `{ responseType: "blob" }` part and check again the `res` variable ?

Comment: ok i tried and i get an ErrorHttpResponse object in the console with message: "Http failure during parsing for url" and in the text property an html string with the information of the files in the remote dir @MartinoBordin

Comment: Try using `{responseType: 'text'}` to avoid the parsin error..then you need to parse the HTML string

Comment: @MartinoBordin yes that works, the problem now is the parsing of the html string. Thank you for the patience

Comment: Then try this one:
`var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');
// do whatever you want with htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');`